# How to add custom property to InternetHeaders of Outlook MailItem

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-redemption

I need to add custom InternetHeader x-auth-guid to existing MailItem in Outlook inbox (in Exchange account) from VSTO add-in. Something like described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633654(v=exchg.80)
but without EWS.
The code using EWS work and do something like:

```
extendedFieldURI.propertyName = "x-auth-guid"
extendedFieldURI.distinguishedPropertySetId = "InternetHeaders"
property.extendedFieldURI = extendedFieldURI
property.value = xauthGuid
message.addExtendedProperty(property)
```

But in add-in both PropertyAccessor like:

```
mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/x-auth-guid",  xauthGuid);
mailItem.Save();
```

and Redemption

```
rdoMail.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/x-auth-guid"] = xauthnGuid;
rdoMail.Save();
```

seems don't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean saying "don't work". Did you have a chance to check the transport headers on the recipient side?

Comment: Also, do you see that property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) on the message in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, it shows it and on the right pane shows {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
PS_INTERNET_HEADERS in NamedProperty section in OutlookSpy. But this is an exising message in the Inbox - not in Sent items. Server side that checks that property on an item in Exchange seems not to see it.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko The issue was related to something else. Now it is working. Sorry.

Comment: Setting it on an Inbox item won't make any difference - it needs to be set on an outgoing message to be included in the MIME headers generated when the message is sent.